# A simple posterior predictive formula

Tags: machine-learning

On MLAPP (Kevin Murphy's Machine Learning text) page 73,
he writes
$$ p(\tilde{x}\in C|\mathcal{D})=\sum_h p(y=1|\tilde{x},h) p(h|\mathcal{D}),$$
where $\tilde{x}\in C$ means the new feature $\tilde{x}$ is classified as $y=1$, $\mathcal{D}$ is data, and $h$ is a hypothesis.

I am puzzled by this formula, it seems to me that it should be
$$ p(\tilde{x}\in C|\mathcal{D})=\sum_h p(y=1|\tilde{x},h,\mathcal{D}) p(h|\mathcal{D})$$

Can anyone confirm?

It's not in the errata, so I am not sure whether my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct. $p(h|D)$ is the posterior distribution and $p(y|x,h)$ is a likelihood. Assuming that there are a countable number of hypotheses, this amounts to integrating the likelihood over the posterior for $h$.

If we knew $h$ we wouldn't need the data to predict. The likelihood depends on $h$ and our belief about $h$ depends on the data.

Comment: Just for OP's future reference: this reasoning is true for the specific classification problem in the book. For more general problems, however, it need not be the case that the hypothesis completely specifies the observation. If you search for "Bayes model averaging", most literature uses your full conditional $p(x|h,D)$. See, for instance: http://www.stat.colostate.edu/~jah/papers/statsci.pdf.